# Semantic differences between percent literals and herdocs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

Looking at some documentation, I saw a multiline string defined using a percent literal:

```
command %Q{
    do this;
    do that;
}
```

In the past, I've always used heredocs when I needed multiline strings:

```
command <<-heredoc
    echo "stuff" | do stuff;
heredoc
```

What are the semantic differences between them?  Is there any reason why I would want to use %Q and not a heredoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a semantic difference, and it doesn't have to do with multiline strings either. *All* strings can be multiline in Ruby. These are all the same string:

```
'a
b
'

"a
b
"

%Q{a
b
}

<<-heredoc
a
b
heredoc
```

The question of which to use is decided by whether you need interpolation and the convenience of escaping characters. For example:

1. Do you need interpolation? If not then `''` or `%q()`
2. Will there be lots of quote characters to escape? Then use `%Q()`
3. Do you want to write a lot of text without thinking about escaping characters? Use heredocs.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. In 2., why can't a heredoc be used? The point of the OP's question is whether there is a need to use `%Q()` over heredoc. You haven't shown any example.

Comment: You could use a heredoc for 2 (though heredoc's always have a trailing newline). Like I said, there are no semantic differences - only technical differences.

Comment: There is also "squiggly heredoc" `<<~heredoc` note the tilde `~`. This will perform an automatic left trim so you don't take in all the whitespace on multi-lined strings that keep indentation with the code. Also another nice life hack: `<<~heredoc.strip` to remove the last trailing `\n`

Answer (score 3):

I tend to evaluate how much text is being used when deciding which to use.

I use `%Q` when there's not a lot of text (for example, a single line), e.g. `%Q|foobar|`. The value that `%Q` provides, is it allows you to easily mix quotes, e.g.

```
%Q|"Get a Job" ~Mom's words|
```

I use "heredoc"s when there is a lot of text that spans multiple lines.

For example, suppose you're pasting a lot of text into a REPL (like the content of a YAML file). Unless you traverse the whole file, you can't be certain whether or not you will have a conflict with whatever `%Q` separator you have chosen. With a "heredoc" you just use some really obscure piece of text that you're fairly certain will not have a conflict, e.g.

```
<<-BatMobilePrettyObscure
... Lots of text ...
BatMobilePrettyObscure
```

As far as I know, semantically, there are just a few small differences:

- `%Q` can only use one character to delimit strings
- `%Q` can be multi-line or single-line
- "heredoc"s must be Multi-line, with the closing "heredoc" *standing alone*
- `%Q` delimiters can be "mashed" up against their strings, e.g. `%Q|foobar|`

Answer (score 2):

There's a funky trick that you can use with heredocs: the first line can be used as if it was a complete string. For example, all of the following examples are valid Ruby code:

```
puts(<<-EOS)
  Hello, world!
EOS

<<-EOS.upcase
  Hello, world!
EOS

puts(<<-EOS.upcase)
  Hello, world!
EOS
```

However, you will not find that very often in the wild. Other than that, they are the same as double quoted strings or `%Q{}` and `%{}` literals, except that you can choose multi-character delimiters. This comes in handy when all of the possible percent literal delimiters may occur in the string. This especially applies to long strings.